# Method to remove from int

Tags: java, recursion

This is what I have been able to come up with so far.

```
  public static int evens(int n)
  {           
  String num = "" + n;
  if (n>1) {

     if (n%2 == 0) {
        return n + evens(n%10);
     }
     else {
        int len = num.length();
        num = num.substring(0, len-1);
        n = Integer.parseInt(num);
        return n + evens(n%10);
     }
  }
  else {
     return n;
  }      
 }
```

My logic is to make the integer a string, then divide by 10 each time to make the next digit (right to left) in the ones place (and using integers the previous digit should be dropped I believe). Then I am trying to use %2 to find the remainder, and if it is not ==0  the digit in the ones place is odd, and to somehow eliminate that digit from the string (by taking the length then taking a substring from 0 to len-1). I think my problems include possibly logic, obviously something is wrong with my syntax, and the first line of the method defining the string causes it to redefine through every recursion, messing it up.

Comment: I sometimes wonder why schools still enforce recursion, when its usage outside of campus is absolutely none. (Before I get burned at stake, I realize that sometimes recursion is good friend when sorting trees  etc., but I still believe recursion is good servant, but cruel master and should be avoided whenever possible)

Comment: n % 10 == 4 so you never get a number that is not n % 2 == 0 and you'll get an stackoverflow exception.

Comment: @TheLaw you are correct about the "usability" of recursion (usually can be prevented by using an iterative approach). But I think you're missing an important point: the universities are *not* trying to prepare you to work in the industry, they're trying to prepare you for higher academic degrees... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compact non-string version:

```
public static int evenDigits(int n) {
    return (n&1) != 0 ? evenDigits1(n/10) : n < 10 ? n : n%10 + evenDigits(n/10)*10;
}
```

Explained:

```
public static int evenDigits(int n) {
    if ((n & 1) != 0) {
        // Last digit is odd, so remove it. Recurse on higher digits
        return evenDigits(n / 10);
    }
    if (n < 10) {
        // Single digit number is even, so we're done
        return n;
    }
    // Keep last digit (it is even). Recurse on higher digits
    return n % 10 + evenDigits(n / 10) * 10;
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, makes so much more sense than what I was trying to do. Only one question, in the first if statement I don't understand the logic. What does the single & do?

Comment: @golden_kiwi It's a [bitwise AND operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND). If you prefer, you can use `n % 2 != 0` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there are a few bugs that are mainly caused by redundant logic, but it can easily get (simplified and) fixed:

```
public static String evenDigits(int n)
{
    if (n > 0) {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            return n % 10 + "" + evenDigits(n / 10);
        } else {
            return evenDigits(n / 10) + "";
        }
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Pay special attention to the "switch" of the parameters in the return statement from:

```
return n + evenDigits(n%10);
```

to:

```
return n % 10 + "" + evenDigits(n / 10);
```

by returning `n % 10` you'll return the current digit you're working on (which is what you want) and send the "rest" of the number recursively by using `n / 10`.

---

A different approach can be, to not use Strings at all. Combining it with an iterative approach (vs. the recursive one that was suggested above) the result is something like the following:

```
public static int evenDigits(int n) {
    int res = 0;
    int mag = 0;
    while (n > 9) {
        int digit = n % 10;
        n /= 10;
        if (digit % 2 == 0) {
            res += Math.pow(10, mag) * digit;
            mag++;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I just tried this, and its mixing up the order of the variables for some reason. Also the return type of the method must be an integer whereas you changed it to a string, this one one aspect that was giving me a lot of trouble earlier.

Comment: I called this method with `System.out.println(evenDigits(7439214))` and it returned `424` as requested. If you want to return an int you can add another method which will call this one and convert the result back from String to int.

Comment: The number that I used in the original post was just an example, for the assignment the program has to work for any integer. Still not really sure why the ordering is mixed up though. Also, I completely agree that it makes more sense as a string, but we are required to return it as an integer. Is there a way to parse the string to an int and return it as an int within the recursive method?

Comment: Not from within the recursive method, you'll need to add another method that will call the recursive method, and that method will convert the result from a string into an int.